# Entity Framework equivalent of the following query?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, t-sql, ado

Can someone tell me how to write an EF query that equals to this:

```
SELECT OI.orderid, 
       OI.inventoryid, 
       VP.vendorid 
FROM   orders O 
       INNER JOIN orderitems OI 
               ON O.orderid = OI.orderid 
       INNER JOIN vendorparts VP 
               ON VP.inventoryid = OI.inventoryid 
WHERE  (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM   vendorparts 
               INNER JOIN vendors 
                       ON vendorparts.vendorid = vendors.vendorid 
                          AND vendors.candropship = 1 
        WHERE  vendorparts.inventoryid = VP.inventoryid 
               AND vendorparts.vendorid IN ( 1, 17 )) > 1
```

I'm trying to do something like this...

```
var q = from o in _context.Orders
            join oi in _context.Orderitems on o.Orderid equals oi.Orderid
            join vp in _context.Vendorparts on oi.Inventoryid equals  vp.Inventoryid
                where (from vp2 in _context.Vendorparts
                       where vp2.Inventoryid == vp.Inventoryid                           
                       select count(*)) > 1
```

but obviously that is syntatctically not allowed.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you failing?

Comment: New to stack overflow vzwick- let me update my original post

Comment: Thanks vzwick , I will give this a shot. wanted to avoid usp.

Comment: vzwick: where in your solution does it account for the condition that vendorparts count must be greater than 1?

Comment: That would be the `.Any()`. FYI, you're better off commenting beneath people's answers if you're addressing those - it was kind of a lucky coincidence I noticed your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long answer:

```
var vendorIds = new int[] { 1, 17 };

_context
    .Orders
    .Join(_context.Orderitems,
        o => o.Orderid,
        oi => oi.Orderid,
        (o, oi) => new { o, oi })
    .Join(_context.Vendorparts,
        o_oi => o_oi.oi.Inventoryid,
        vp => vp.Inventoryid,
        (o_oi, vp) => new { o_oi.o, o_oi.oi, vp })
    .Where(o_oi_vp => _context.Vendorparts
        .Where(vp
            => vp.Inventoryid == o_oi_vp.vp.Inventoryid
            && vendorIds.Contains(vp.Vendorid))
        .Join(_context.Vendors.Where(v => v.Candropship),
            vp => vp.Vendorid,        
            v => v.Vendorid,
            (vp, v) => new { vp, v })
        .Any())
    .Select(o_oi_vp => new {
        o_oi_vp.oi.orderid, 
        o_oi_vp.oi.inventoryid, 
        o_oi_vp.vp.vendorid 
    });
```

Short answer: use a stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks. Not very pretty and I will use the sp approach.